# Remove Row Element in FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How do I remove the Row element when using FOR XML

For example when I do:

```
SELECT Col FROM TABLE FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

It returns for each row of data:

```
<table><Col>Value</Col></table>
```

I would like it to only return this for each row of data:

```
<Col>Value</Col>
```

Is there a default option when using FOR XML or does it have to be parsed/trimmed seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 1 FROM TABLE AS Col FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

OR

```
SELECT 1 AS Col  FROM TABLE FOR XML PATH('')
```